# Multiple items selection from ListView

Tags: qt, qml

I want to select multiple items from a `ListView`. In `C++` I would have done something like this

```
if (clicked_card->is_selected) {
    clicked_card->is_selected = false;
    int i = 0;
    while(selected_cards[i] != clicked_card) i++;
    selected_cards.erase(selected_cards.begin() + i);
} else {
    clicked_card->is_selected = true;
    selected_cards.push_back(clicked_card);
}
```

The above code uses pointer for comparison. So how to so such selection in `QML`. The solution I've come up with is something like this

**Card.qml**

```
Image {
    id: delegate
    property bool isSelected: false
    ...
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: {
            if(isSelected === true) {
                isSelected = false;
                gameScene.deselectCard(selectSeq);
            }
            else {
                isSelected = true;
                gameScene.selectCard({'opParam': opParam, 'selectSeq': selectSeq});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameScene.qml**

```
Item {
    id: gameScene
    property var selectedCards: []

    signal selectCard(variant userData)
    onSelectCard: {
        gameScene.selectedCards.push(userData)
    }

    signal deselectCard(variant userData)
    onDeselectCard: {
        for (var i = 0; i < gameScene.selectedCards.length; i += 1) {
            if (gameScene.selectedCards[i].selectSeq == userData) {
                gameScene.selectedCards.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that I'm storing property `isSelected` in a delegate which is created and destroyed by the system. So this is giving me false solution. Is there any better way of multiple selection or any improvements in the solution ? I'm using `model` from C++ by subclassing `QAbstractListModel`.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer in `Qt` documentation. I simply have to use `[DelegateModel][1]`. It has a `group` property, for every group defined in a `DelegateModel` two attached properties are added to each delegate item. The first of the form `DelegateModel.in*GroupName*` holds whether the item belongs to the group and the second `DelegateModel.*groupName*Index` holds the index of the item in that group.

```
  import QtQuick 2.0
  import QtQml.Models 2.2

  Rectangle {
      width: 200; height: 100

      DelegateModel {
          id: visualModel
          model: ListModel {
              ListElement { name: "Apple" }
              ListElement { name: "Orange" }
          }

          groups: [
              DelegateModelGroup { name: "selected" }
          ]

          delegate: Rectangle {
              id: item
              height: 25
              width: 200
              Text {
                  text: {
                      var text = "Name: " + name
                      if (item.DelegateModel.inSelected)
                          text += " (" + item.DelegateModel.selectedIndex + ")"
                      return text;
                  }
              }
              MouseArea {
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  onClicked: item.DelegateModel.inSelected = !item.DelegateModel.inSelected
              }
          }
      }

      ListView {
          anchors.fill: parent
          model: visualModel
      }
  }
```

Other solution would have been to move the property `isSelected` to C++ data model and use a getter and setter function to update the changes.

Comment: I tried to implement this with no success. The DelegateModel property is not attached to my delegate. Always shows as null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution. Use QPair or QPair to store the state of all of your item.

```
typedef QPair<int, bool> ItemState;
```

Enable multiple selection in your list o table:

```
ui->tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

And when you want to select a collection, just try something like this:

```
QList<ItemState> collection;
foreach (ItemState& el , collection) {
    const int row = el.first;
    const bool state = el.second;
    const QModelIndex& index = ui->tableView->model()->index(row, 0);
    ui->tableView->selectionModel()->select(index, state ? QItemSelectionModel::Select : QItemSelectionModel::Deselect );
}
```

You should update your collection data, everytime you modify the data in the model (add, remove o move elements). When the user clicks in a card, just handle the clicked event and modify your collection item state, and recall the loop.